# How to access computed data from other scala file?

Tags: scala, future

I need to access this data *mapData* from Calculation.scala. The way I call the function in Final.scala is as seen below.

When I see the output of fetch_data() or print it I see *Future(< not completed >)* and *result* is empty. I do not know how to wait until all data is downloaded and then access mapData? MAy I know how to do it? I am new to scala. In C++ I am aware of callbacks and handling is easy there. But in scala I a using Future, Await or OnComplete, but not clear how to do it.

```
  Final.Scala   

    object finalComputation {

     val calculationInfo = new Calculaton()

     calclulationInfo.fetch_data()

     val result = calculationInfo.getMapData()


     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      ........
     }
    }



 Calculation.scala

    class Calculation {

     var mapData = Map.empty[String, String]

     def createMapData(metricItem: ActualMetrics) = {
        mapData += (metricItem._1  -> metricItem._2)
     }

     def getMapData() = {
       mapData 
     }

     def fetch_data() = {
     val totalData: Future[Done] =
       querApi
         .getData()
            .map { data =>
            (data)
           }
       }
     }

    Await.result(totalData, Duration.Inf).runForeach(unit => {
     createMapData(parse.From(totalData))
  })
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, by starter don't mix concurrency with mutability.
Second, don't create imperative APIs that require some specific call order.
Third, `Future` is just a fancy wrapper over callbacks.
And fourth, don't initiate computations before the `main`

```scala
// file: Calculation.scala
class Calculation(queryApi: Api) {
  def fetchData(): Future[Map[String, String]] =
    querApi.getData().map { data =>
      data.view.map { metric =>
        val ActualMetrics(key, value) = parse(metric)
        key -> value
      }.toMap
    }
}

// file: Main.scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val calculation = new Calculation(...)
    val dataF = calculation.fetchData()
    val result = dataF.map { data =>
        // Here you can process the fetched data
        // It may be flatMap or foreach, instead of map;
        // depending on what you want to do, check the Scaladoc
    }

    // I don't use future, but I think here you need to do a final await of result.
    // In order to avoid the program to finish before the async computation.
  }
}
```

I had to assume some types, but I hope this gives you a general idea of what to do.

My advice, pick any **Scala** course / book / tutorial and properly learn the language.